# How to extract sub-strings for a collection of text?

Tags: java, regex, string, extract, information-extraction

I extracted text from pdf document.  .. I want to extract some particular fields in it using **java**..

The portion of text ..

> US00RE44697E 
>  (i9) United States 
>  (12) Reissued Patent (10)
>   Patent Number: RE44,697 E 
>  Jones et al. (45) Date of
>   ReissuedPatent: Jan. 7, 2014 
>  (54) ENCRYPTIONPROCESSORWITH SHARED
>   
>  MEMORY INTERCONNECT
>  (75) Inventors: David E.Jones, Ottawa
>   (CA); Cormac 
>  M.O'Connell, Carp (CA) 
>  (73) Assignee: Mosaid
>   Technologies Incorporated, 
>  Ottawa, Ontario (CA) 
>  (21)
>   Appl.No.: 13/603,137 
>  (22) Filed: Sep. 4, 2012 
>  Related U.S.
>   Patent Documents 
>  Reissue of:  
>  (64) Patent No.: 
>  Issued:
>   
>  Appl. No.: 
>  Filed: 
>  6,088,800 
>  Jul. 11, 2000 
>   09/032,029 
>  Feb. 27, 1998 
>  (51) Int.CI. 
>  G06F 21/00
>   (2013.01) 
>  (52) U.S. CI. 
>  USPC .............713/189; 713/190;
>   713/193; 380/28; 
>  380/33; 380/52 
>  (58) Field of Classification
>   Search 
>  None

Now my mission is to extract fields form it and give to strings.. that is

the text `(10) Patent Number: RE44,697 E` will be extracted as `String pat_no= " RE44,697 E"`

the text `(54) ENCRYPTIONPROCESSORWITH SHARED
MEMORY INTERCONNECT` will be extracted as `String title= "ENCRYPTIONPROCESSORWITH SHARED
MEMORY INTERCONNECT"`

the extremely  irregular text block

> (64) Patent No.: 
>  Issued: 
>  Appl. No.: 
>  Filed: 
>   6,088,800 
>  Jul. 11, 2000 
>  09/032,029 
>  Feb. 27, 1998

have to be extracted as

```
String pat_no_org = "6,088,800";
String issued = "jul.11,2000" 
String filed = "feb 27 ,1998"
......
```

like this..

**My Works**

First i used the string.split , string.substring , string,indexof and even apache string utils , but none helped.. Because the text are scattered , above methods doesn't helped.. I also tried regular expressions ,but since I very weak in it  I can't program .

Please tell me how to achieve my objective using java ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think it will help if you post what regex you tried and write where it failed.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/                   

I read this site and applied some.. But struggled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex, I would split it in 3 parts:

1.) `(10) Patent Number` the regex could look like this:

```
\(10\)\s*Patent Number:\s*([\w,]+)
```

as a java string:

```
"\\(10\\)\\s*Patent Number:\\s*([\\w,]+)"
```

The matches for the first parenthesized group will be in `[1]`.

- `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]` any kind of *white-space*.
- `\w` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` *word-characters*, together with `,` in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- Some characters have [special meanings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regex. They have to be escaped with a backslash.

---

2.) `(54) ENCRYPT...`

A pattern could look like:

```
(?s)\(54\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\(\d|$\))
```

as a java string:

```
"(?s)\\(54\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?=\\(\\d|$\\))"
```

- `(?s)` The [s modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) equals Pattern.DOTALL where the dot matches new-lines too.
- `(?=\(\d|$\))` a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used, to match `(.*?)` [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) any amount of any characters until another `(` followed by a digit `|` or string-end `$` ([anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for end) is seen.

---

3.) For the other desired 3 parts I would try to reflect formatting of the input with the pattern. This requires, that all data is constructed compatible. A pattern could look like this:

```
(?s)\(64\).*?Filed:\s*([\d,]+)\s*(\w+\.\s*\d+,\s*\d+)\s*\n[\d+][^\n]+\n\s*(\w+\.\s*\d+,\s*\d+)
```

as a java string:

```
"(?s)\\(64\\).*?Filed:\\s*([\\d,]+)\\s*(\\w+\\.\\s*\\d+,\\s*\\d+)\\s*\\n[\\d+][^\\n]+\\n\\s*(\\w+\\.\\s*\\d+,\\s*\\d+)"
```

- [\n](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp) matches a newline.

Matches will be in `[1]` e.g. *6,088,800*, `[2]` e.g. *Jul. 11, 2000* and `[3]` e.g. *Feb. 27, 1998*.

For getting started with regex, this is too much information at once :)

Comment: @user3190934 On stack we accept and upvote instead of thanks :)